# Firebase always returning that email is already registered

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented the basics of [this](https://github.com/sararob/angular2base) into my application but I am having an issue where it is always returning an error that specifies that the user is email is already registered on an empty firebase.

This is the function that registers the user:

```
registerUser()
{
    if (this.newUser.password === this.newUser.passwordConfirm)
    {
        this.firebaseRef.createUser({email: this.newUser.email, password: this.newUser.password}, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Invalid passwords");
    }

}
```

and that is always returning this error: `user-registration.component.ts:34 Error: The specified email address is already in use.(…)`. Like I said, the firebase is empty and I am 100% certain I have initialized firebase with the correct URL

This is my registration component in Angular2

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseEventPipe} from "../firebasepipe";
import {User} from "../classes/user";



@Component({
    selector: 'registration',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/registration.component.html',
    pipes: [FirebaseEventPipe],

})

export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit{

    private firebaseUrl: string;
    private firebaseRef: Firebase;

    newUser: User;

    submitted = false;

    constructor() {
        this.firebaseUrl = "https://<<myfirebaseurl>>.firebaseio.com/";
        this.firebaseRef = new Firebase(this.firebaseUrl);
    }

    registerUser()
    {
        if (this.newUser.password === this.newUser.passwordConfirm)
        {
            this.firebaseRef.createUser({email: this.newUser.email, password: this.newUser.password}, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Invalid passwords");
        }

    }

    ngOnInit():any {
        this.newUser = {email: '', password: '', passwordConfirm: ''}
    }

    // TODO: Remove this when we're done
    get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.newUser); }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this.newUser.email isn't an empty value?

Comment: Yes. console.logging it right before execution shows that it isn't an empty value.

Comment: @oori even directly adding a string into the createUser function returns the same error

Comment: If you go to your Firebase dashboard (`https://<<myfirebaseurl>>.firebaseio.com/`) and then to the "Login & Auth" tab, are there any users in the "Registered Users" table?

Comment: Yeah they were being created. I hadn't noticed that before.